# boto3 dynamodb query with number key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to do a reasonably simple query on a dynamodb. When I go on the AWS Console I can setup the query with appid (Number) = 11510 and I get two results (as expected).

What I want is to be able to use boto3 for this.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1',
                aws_access_key_id='<deleted>',
                aws_secret_access_key='<deleted>')
table = dynamodb.Table('site_logging')
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('schema_name').eq('<schema>'),
    FilterExpression=Key('appid').eq(11510)
)
print(response)
print('Response items {}'.format(response['Items']))
```

But this returns 0 results.

If I change my FilterExpression to another Key, for example `Key('appname').eq('call')` I get a large number of responses. So my access should be good.

There are some "appid" values that will return results so I know the spelling of that part is correct :-).

If I change `.eq(11510)` to `.gt(11510)` I get results but not 11510. Of the ones that I do get returned I can try the `.eq` on it and I get a result.

So, generally things appear to be working, but I am not getting results that I see in the AWS console.

Comment: Looks like for the given schema_name, appid = 11510 doesn't exists. Hope you found it by now.

Comment: Haven't figured it out yet.  When I go into DynamoDB on AWS I can do the query with the proper schema_name and appid of 11510 and I see two results.  This is what I find confusing is that I see results in the AWS console but I don't see the results from the above query.

Comment: Ah, I believe I now have it solved.  `A single Query or Scan operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before any FilterExpression is applied to the results.`  I added a second Key on the KeyConditionExpression ` & Key('datetime').gt('2017-01-11 00:00:00')` and I now am getting back the two results.